# there is no alert prompt when run this simple javascript code?

Tags: javascript

```
var foo = function(){};
foo.prototype.value = 5;
foo.prototype.addValue = function(){ foo.value = 6; }
function bar(func)
{
func(); // I'm running the function!
}
bar(foo.addValue); // pass in the function 
alert(foo.value); // it's now 6!
```

Why is the no alert prompt when running this JavaScript code?

Comment: That code is wrong; either you mistyped it or the book is very bad.  `addValue` should be using `this`.

Comment: In 'bar(func)' function you are trying to call 'func()' which is undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct code should be

```
var foo = function(){};
foo.prototype.value = 5;
foo.prototype.addValue = function(){ foo.value = 6; }
function bar(func)
{
    func(); // I'm running the function!
}
bar(foo.prototype.addValue); // pass in the function
alert(foo.value);
```

or

```
var foo = function(){};
foo.prototype.value = 5;
foo.prototype.addValue = function(){ foo.value = 6; }
function bar(func)
{
    func(); // I'm running the function!
}
bar(new foo().addValue); // pass in the function
alert(foo.value);
```

Since you are declaring a prototype called addValue, foo itself does not contain addValue. To refer to that function, you have to use foo.prototype.addValue. Note that in this case, foo contains both foo.prototype.value with a value of 5, and foo.value with a value of 6.

Alternatively, if the intention is to create a new object, then the object will inherit the addValue function, so calling new foo().addValue works.

Answer (score 0):

Well, refactoring your code would give:

```
var foo = {
    value: 5,
    addValue: function(){
        foo.value = 6;
    }
};

function bar(func){
    func(); // I'm running the function!
}

bar(foo.addValue); // pass in the function 
alert(foo.value); // it's now 6!
```

Setting `foo.prototype.addValue` won't help you to define `foo.addValue`.

And the reason for using `foo.value` instead of `this.value` is to resolve scope problems when calling via `bar()`